# Java Multiple types in one enum

Tags: java, enums

Basically, I've been trying to have an enum with multiple types in it. I found what i was trying to achieve but it was in TypeScript:

```
export enum ability_ranges {
    ONE = 1,
    THREE = 3,
    FIVE = 5,
    SEVEN = 7,
    NINE = 9,
    ELEVEN = 11,
    ALL = "all",
}
```

All I have so far is this:

```
public enum ability_ranges {
        ONE (1),
        THREE (3),
        FIVE (5),
        SEVEN (7),
        NINE (9),
        ELEVEN (11),
        ALL ("all");
        
        private int range;
        private String text;

        public int getValue() {
            return range;
        }
        
        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }
        
        private ability_ranges(int range) {
            this.range = range;
        }

        ability_ranges(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }
        
    }
```

I do believe this would work, I was just wondering if there was a more elegant way of achieving this?

Comment: That will not work.

Comment: Nope, no more elegant way. What you're doing is good. --- *FYI:* This question might have been a better candidate for asking on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Are you sure you *want* an `enum`? It sounds like you might want a simple collection of constants in a class. An `enum` implies some coherent common type.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo The enum *is* the coherent common type.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to explain what you're trying to accomplish with this type rather than present a finished version with no explanation.

The definition you have is correct Java, and it will do *something*, but it's awkward and error prone. For example, if you say

```
ability_ranges a = ALL;
System.out.println(a.getValue());
```

then the output will be `0`. That doesn't make sense. You'd normally want an error in that case.  On the other hand if you say:

```
ability_ranges a = THREE;
System.out.println(a.getText());
```

then the output will be `null`.  Again, not making a lot of sense.

A closer approximation of the Typescript would be:

```
public enum AbilityRange {
  ONE (1),
  THREE (3),
  FIVE (5),
  SEVEN (7),
  NINE (9),
  ELEVEN (11),
  ALL ("all");
        
  private Object value;

  public int getInt() {
    return (int) value;
  }
        
  public String getText() {
    return (String) value;
  }
        
  private AbilityRange(Object value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

Now if your attempt to get the contents doesn't match the enum value, you'll see a `ClassCastException`, which is probably a better outcome.

However I still have a hard time seeing how this definition will be employed in a useful way.